# asking for the unicode of letter conjunctions

Tags: pdf, unicode

I occasionally encounter some special character while parsing PDF documents. They are actually two English letters, like 'fi', 'tt', or 'ti', but visually they look like conjuncted and they actually exist in PDF string as one character.

I checked the 'ToUnicode' for these characters, but I just found the 'ToUnicode' CMap table are disrupted, therefore I cannot find their unicode.

For example, `<012E> Tj` will print `fi` like attached picture. But in its corresponding Font's ToUnicode CMap: `<012E> <0001>`, which is meaningless.

Could anybody let me know their unicode code point? Possible to find it from the corresponding font program?

Thanks for any advice.

`fi`: [image]

`tt`: [image]

`ti`: [image]

Comment: These are called ligatures – might help you search.

Comment: yes, that's helpful! Thanks @lenz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, what you call *letter conjunctions* usually is known as *ligatures*. Thus, I will use that term here from now on.

Unicode discourages the use of specific code points for ligatures:

> The existing ligatures exist basically for compatibility and round-tripping with non-Unicode character sets. Their use is discouraged. No more will be encoded in any circumstances.
>
> Ligaturing is a behavior encoded in fonts: if a modern font is asked to display “h” followed by “r”, and the font has an “hr” ligature in it, it can display the ligature. Some fonts have no ligatures, while others (especially fonts for non-Latin scripts) have hundreds of ligatures. It does not make sense to assign Unicode code points to all these font-specific possibilities.

*([Unicode FAQ on ligatures](http://www.unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html))*

Thus, you should not use the existing ligature code points.

You appear to attempt to find the correct **ToUnicode** mapping for ligature glyphs. For this simply remember that the values of **ToUnicode** mappings do not need to be *single code points* but may be *multiple ones*:

> *n* **beginbfchar**
> *srcCode dstString*
> **endbfchar**
> where *dstString* may be a string of up to 512 bytes.

*(ISO 32000-1, section 9.10.3 ToUnicode CMaps)*

Concerning your example, therefore:

> For example, `<012E> Tj` will print `fi` like attached picture. But in its corresponding Font's ToUnicode CMap: `<012E> <0001>`, which is meaningless.

Simply use

```
<012E> <00660069>
```

If you want to use ligature code points nonetheless, query the [Wikipedia article on Orthographic Ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature), it lists some ligature code points. In particular `<FB01>` for `ﬁ`, so for your example:

```
<012E> <FB01>
```

But remember, their use is discouraged.

Comment: To repeat: ligatures are font specific (in strict definition, so also inside a font family [font in classic sense]). Italic have different ligatures, mono-spaces could have none, and cursive (also in English) has many ligatures. Also context is important. On math we do not want ligatures. ZWNJ (U+200C) is used to avoid ligatures.

Comment: Indeed. And ZWJ is used to encourage ligatures.